# Is there any method in selenium to find what is the type of tag for the element we have to find

Tags: javascript, selenium

In selenium is there any way to find out the type of tag
In my automation page some fields may change.say first filed value is greater the second filed become input text if first is IN then drop down like that. 
so is there any java script executor method to find tag name from the identified element

I have triedfollowing 2 methods
1)
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));

```
     String tag =(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(" return ele.tagName ");
     System.out.println(tag);
```

2)
 String xpath="input[id='identifierId']";

```
     String mainURL =(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(" return (document.querySelector(\"xpath \").tagName) ");
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This code is in Java and it'll give you the tag name.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).getTagName()
```